# Can neural networks do face swapping, or is that the wrong approach?

Tags: machine-learning

I've been studying and working with neural networks for a few years, and I'm trying to figure out if they can handle high quality face swapping like we see here:

https://gfycat.com/yearlynewbarb

or if more specialized machine learning systems are the only viable tool for it. Is this something that is even reasonable to approach with neural networks? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, you missed the "deepfakes" on Reddit. Google it at your own risk: NSFW.

So, the answer is resounding YES, not only still images but movies at quite an amazing quality. If only it was used for higher purposes :)

The most popular app to my knowledge was FakeApp, and AFAIK it was on Keras/Tensorflow/CUDA platform. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I was under the impression that it is in fact NN AI.

Comment: Like this library for example, I believe doesnt use neural networks at all: https://github.com/shaoanlu/faceswap-GAN

Comment: @Viziionary A GAN or [generative adversarial network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network) is indeed a neural network (two, in fact)

Comment: GAN is quite an advanced NN

Answer (score 0):

Michael Jackson definitely knew of the technology, and that was before the neural network boom.

See the last minute of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2AitTPI5U0.